# Onchange event after selecting in select dropdown list in ZEND

Tags: php, zend-framework, html-select, selectionchanged

I have a view with a dropdown list using select tag and I want to how can i have an event or an onchange event after selecting a value in my dropdown.

here is my code in index.phtml

```
    <?php if (count($users)): ?>
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
   <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url('user/edit', array('id' => $user->id)); ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($user->email); ?></td>
        <td>
            <select name="level">

            <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>

            <?php if ($level == 1): ?>
                 <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2">Manager</option>
                 <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
             <?php elseif ($level == 2): ?>
                 <option value="1" >Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" selected="selected">Manager</option>
                 <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
               <?php elseif ($level == 3): ?>
                 <option value="1" >Administrator</option>
                 <option value="2" >Manager</option>
                 <option value="3" selected="selected">HR Staff</option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url('user/delete', array('id' => $user->id)); ?>" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" rel="tooltip" title="Delete this user"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
<h3>There are no registered users available.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use javascript onchange function .
<select name="level" onchange="changeTest()">

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me hints on how can i implement it?

Comment: ok, i will try to implement this. thanks

Comment: let me know my answer solve your issue or not ?

Comment: Hey, thnx, i tried this code
      <select name="level" onchange="changeLevel(this)>
     <script type='text/javascript'>

function changeLevel(obj){
  alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
}

</script>

but unfortunately the select options were not functioning, my first select option which is Administrator is not showing and the function also not functioning i guess

Comment: have you check my working example ?  go to this link ..
http://jsfiddle.net/Le6bun1j/2/

Comment: yes, but i donk know why it is not functioning well on mine.

Comment: can you share your new code ???

Comment: <select name="level" onchange="changeLevel(this)>
   
            <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>
            
            <?php if ($level == 1): ?>
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
     <option value="2">Manager</option>
     <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
<?php endif; ?>
          </select>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeLevel(obj){
  alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
}

</script>

Comment: please update code in your question.. : )

Comment: Im sorry i missed a double quote mark haha my bad. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create javascript function and put function in select box onchange event.

check working example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le6bun1j/2/)

```
<script>
 function changeTest(obj){
    alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
  }
</script>

 <select name="level" onChange="changeTest(this)">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
             <option value="2">Manager</option>
             <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
 </select>
```